# Linearly independent vectors with a missing coordinate

Tags: vectors

For what values of $\lambda$, are $a_1=(\lambda, −1, −1)$, $a_2=(−1, \lambda, −1)$, $a_3=(−1, −1, \lambda) \in \Bbb R^3$,  linearly independent?

From what I know, if $3$ vectors belong $\Bbb R^3$, then they are linearly independent so I don't know how to proceed with this problem. At first glance they seem linearly independent for any $\lambda$ except $-1$.

Comment: I would say, if 3 vectors belong a plane in R3, then they are linearly dependent.

Comment: Try to work out a determinant of the matrix. The matrix must be regular if vectors are linearly independent. That should tell you something.

Comment: I know that the determinant of the matrix shouldn't be equal to 0 and I get λ³-3λ-2≠0 but then what ?

Comment: You can guess the root $\lambda=-1$ "by inspection", or simply by noting that the three vectors become identical when $\lambda=-1$. Factoring $\lambda +1$ out leaves a quadratic which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the determinant of the matrix is $\lambda^3 -3\lambda -2$. If the rows are to be linearly independent, we need nonzero determinant. So we set  $\lambda^3 -3\lambda -2 = 0$ and figure out which values $\lambda$ cannot be.

Using synthetic division, we see $\lambda = 2$ is a root of that equation and that it factors to $(\lambda -2)(\lambda^2 +2\lambda +1) = (\lambda -2)(\lambda +1)^2 $.

Then setting $(\lambda -2)(\lambda +1)^2 = 0$, we see this only occurs when $\lambda =2, \lambda = -1$.

Then the rows are linearly independent when $\lambda \neq 2, \lambda \neq -1$.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your determinant is

$$\lambda^3-3\lambda-2$$

$$=\lambda^3+1-3(\lambda+1)$$

$$=(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2-\lambda-2)$$

$$(\lambda+1)^2(\lambda-2).$$

thus, the three vectors are linearly independent if 
$\lambda\neq -1$ and $\lambda\neq 2$.